# How to transform a pandas dataframe with two index columns and one value column into a heat map?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a df which looks like this when exported to excel. Where columns A and B a index columns.
[excel output of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dszRv.png)

How to transform into this format?
[wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e0eR.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```py
df = df.unstack(level=-1)
```